# change default change_list view for only filtered views

Tags: python, django, django-views

We are in process of removing `count(*)` queries that are fired for admin page, we don't want that query to be fired on the landing page but should be fired on filtered pages. Is there any way in django that we can customize filtered views but not landing views. I read through the documentation, went through the code, but didn't find anything, so asking here.

I have found some information about the places where the count queries are firing, but I couldn't find way to modify change list view based on filtered and normal views.

Answer (score 0):

So, finally we found the answer.

In django we have an attribute called `show_full_result_count` for admin pages which disables count query on filtered pages to show the full count. 
[Refer to this picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uLH5W.png). When we put that to `False`, it won't show that number there, [See this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yp15Y.png).

Here's the code for it.

```
class SomemodelAdmin(models.Admin):
    show_full_result_count = False
    list_display = ()
admin.models.register(Somemodel, SomemodelAdmin)
```

This will save us from reducing count queries to half. The whole logic around this can be found on `django/contrib/admin/views/main.py` and this `django/contrib/admin/templates/admin/search_form.html`

A strong note here is if you have overridden any template, make sure the template doesn't have constraint on `show_full_result_count` attribute. We actually overridden the base template, that have the condition with `full_result_count` that costs us a bug which hides the admin actions, for this we have an attribute defined called `show_admin_actions` we have to use that.